# django set image src path

Tags: python, django, image, static

I want to set an image as a submit button form:

```
<form action="/final" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="niloofar">
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="cat.jpg">
</form>
```

The image is in the template directory and the image is not shown.
How should I manage it with `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`?

Should I make a directory called `static` and put the image there?

And how the form should be changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to properly configure your static files. More info can be found [in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)

Additionally, make sure you are writing the correct path the image, as shown in the docs:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now some changes are there to be noted.
You should not load your static files with

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Instead you should write

```
{% load static%}
```

And in source (denoted as src), you should give path of image file from static folder located in your directory. Not from the local resources.